# Current carrying wire to suspend in midair?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

A straight current carrying wire is inserted in a region of space where a strong magnetic field is directed vertically downward. How can the wire be oriented so that it is suspended in midair by the magnetic force.

Well, I dont know what to do with that magnetic field. But this is what I did.

Force on the current carrying wire, $F = BIl$

Weight of the wire, $F' = mg$

For them to suspend, $F = F'$
i.e, $BIl = mg$

in which I'm stuck. How do I determine the orientation of the wire?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Force on the current carrying wire is actually described as $$\vec F= i(\vec l \times \vec B)=ilB\sin \theta \,\ \hat n$$ where $\hat n$ denotes the normal to the plane containing $l$ and $B$ and $\theta$ is the angle between the arc length vector (actually written $d\vec l$) and the magnetic field vector $\vec B$.

So when you are equating this force with the weight, you actually equate their magnitudes, and get $$|ilB\sin \theta \,\ \hat n|=mg$$ or $$ Bil\sin \theta =mg $$ or, $$ \sin \theta =\frac{mg}{Bil} $$

Its the value of $\theta$ from where we get to find the orientation from.